# Play Flash file under WinCE?

Tags: flash, windows-mobile, mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

Is it possible to play a Flash file under WinCE?  I know there is a player for Windows Mobile, but WinCE seems to not have one.  It seems like you can license a player from Adobe for WinCE but I have not had any luck getting information from Adobe.  I found this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/81045c07-8d60-4be6-95a0-be3b42bdad81) that mentions using a AxShockwaveFlashObjects using C# and .NET Compact Framework.  Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Adobe Flash Lite](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashlite/), which is [licensed from B-Square](http://www.bsquare.com/adobe-flashplayerflash-lite.aspx).